# Redux useSelector gets called 3 times and only 3rd time returns the data list for .map()

Tags: reactjs, redux

i am struggling with getting data from my redux state. I am using saga to fetch lambda function that gives me a list of projects from a github account. everything works the projects are fetched and saved to the state. in my component i am using `useSelector` hook to get the projects from my state and display them using `map()`.

The problem is that for some reason looks like the hook is called three times and the first two times the projects list isynt set yet and i get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Projects Component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Projects.scss";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function Projects() {
  const projects = useSelector((state) => state.projects);
  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state.isLoading);

  console.log('PROJECTS', projects)
  return (
    <section className="Projects" id="work">
      <h2 className="Projects__title Projects__title--portfolio">My Work</h2>
      { !isLoading ? projects.projects.map((project, index) => {
        <div className="Projects__portfolio">
          <p>HELLLO</p>
          <a href={project.html_url} className={`Projects__portfolio--img${index}`}></a>
        </div>
      }) : null}
    </section>
  );
}

export default Projects;
```

Reducer:

```
import { ActionTypes } from "../types";

const initialState = {
  projects: [],
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
};

const projectsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.GET_PROJECTS_REQUEST: {
      return {
        isLoading: true
      }
    }
    case ActionTypes.GET_PROJECTS_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        isLoading: false,
        projects: action.payload,
      };
    }
    // case ActionTypes.GET_PROJECTS_FAILED:
    //   return {
    //     error: action.message,
    //   };
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};

export default projectsReducer;
```

SAGA:

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, fork } from "redux-saga/effects";
import {ActionTypes } from '../types';
import * as actionProjects from '../actions';
import * as http from '../../api/httpClient';

function* fetchProjects() {
  try {
    const result = yield call(http.getProjects);
    yield put(actionProjects.getProjectsSuccess(JSON.parse(result.data.body)));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
      yield put({ type: "GET_PROJECTS_FAILED", message: error.message });
  }
}

function* watchGetProjectsRequest() {
  yield takeEvery(ActionTypes.GET_PROJECTS_REQUEST, fetchProjects);
}

const projectsSagaResult = [fork(watchGetProjectsRequest)];

export default projectsSagaResult;
```

This shows the console log from the component its self and as you can see it is called 3 times and only the third time it returns the list of projects and i guess this is why i get the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First render, `isLoading` is `false` (because set as false in your initialState). So your `!isLoading` is `true` and so it tries the `map` which fails because `projects` is an empty array, so `projects.projects` do not exists (and so cannot map on it)

Second render because you're fetching your datas, so `isLoading` goes to `true`

And third render is when you get back your datas from backend.

Many ways to fix your error:

1/ set `isLoading` to `true` by default in your initialState

2/ use conditional chaining to check if array exists `projects.projects?.map(....)`

3/ in your reducer, do not store full payload but only `projects` to avoid unecessary nested datas `projects: action.payload.projects`

Pick the one your prefer :)

Comment: I agree on everything except on the 2nd point, the optional chaining should be projects?.projects.map(...). Great anyway! :)

Comment: Not with his configuration as `projects` is set by default to `[]` in his `initialState`, so `projects?.` will pass to `projects?.projects` and `map` will fail :) But I agree, `projects?.projects?.map(...)` is even better :)

Comment: @dbuchet thx for your answer it contained multiple bits of informations that lead me to a fix, first yes the isLoading was wrong but the chaining was the key. I also reduced the number of `projects?.projects?.projects?.map(...)` but changing my reducer to: `projects: action.payload.projects,`